Promise.allSettled returning status as "fulfilled" even though API call is failed and showing status as 404
I have a Promise.allSettled which takes two API. Even though the second API is failed and returned 404 the promise status shows 'fulfilled'.
  async function loadLivePrerequisites() {
    try {
      const API_ENDPOINTS = getRequiredApis()

      // [0] -> join link, [1] -> user name
      const response = await Promise.allSettled(API_ENDPOINTS);

      const joinLink = response[0].status === "fulfilled" ? response[0].value.data : undefined
      setLiveDetails(joinLink)

      let userName: string;
      if(response[1].status === "fulfilled") {
        userName = response[1].value.data.name
      } else {
        userName = userNameGenerator(user.firstName, user.lastName)
      }
      setUserName(userName)
    } catch(error) { 
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

response:
screenshot
network error (404):
screenshot
I was expecting the status would be "rejected" and code inside the if statement would not be executed. Not sure if it is something wrong from my end or my lack of knowledge on how promise.allSettled work. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

a 404 doesn't necessarily reject a request - for instance, a fetch won't reject on a 404 - also, code in the request could be handling the error - we can't tell, you haven't shown anything about the reqeust code

Like @JaromandaX says, look at the MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch  did you just forget to check for response.ok?

Oh, you tagged axios - that should reject a 404, but of course, your code that does the request may be wrong - again, we can't tell, we can't see it

My doubt is, in what all conditions the promise will give status "rejected" if it is not giving when request fails with 404. @JaromandaX

Will look into it. @Keith, Thanks for your help.

without your code that actually does the request, only you can answer why
